# Using the remote function of jquery validation to check user existence

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I want to user the Jquery Validator plugin to validate a user form. There are firstname,lastname and email which are required. I also want to validate if the user already exists in the system based on the combination of firstname,lastname and email. I don't know how to write the rule for such requirement. Please help. Thanks.

```
$("#user").validate( {
            rules : {
            firstname : {
                required : true,
                remote: {
                  url : "../ajax/checkExisitingUse",
                  data: { lastname:  $('#lastname').val(),
                      email:  $('#email').val()
                        }
                type:post
                }

            },
            lastname : {
                required : true
            },
            email : {
                required : true,
                email : true
            }})
```

Comment: The `remote` rule, just like the other rules, is for checking the data within a single field.  In other words, if you need to check the entire form against the server, then you'll need to submit the entire form to the server.   But to submit the full form to the server, it needs to pass your jQuery Validation first... catch-22.  You should reconsider your entire approach.  Perhaps the part that checks if the user exists should solely be done via your _server-side_ validation, then simply reload a blank form and a message when it fails.

Comment: Otherwise, just use one of your three fields to determine if a user exists.  After all, you should have a single unique key.  Example:  What if you have ten unique users with the same common name, like John Smith? But since they're really ten different people, only the email addresses will be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem I can see is how the data is read for the ajax request... it should be

```
$("#user").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            remote: {
                url: "../ajax/checkExisitingUse",
                data: {
                    lastname: function () {
                        return $('#lastname').val();
                    },
                    email: function () {
                        return $('#email').val();
                    }
                },
                type: post
            }

        },
        lastname: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        }
    }
});
```

and the resource `../ajax/checkExisitingUse` must return `true` if the value is value, else you can return a string message indicating the error or false, undefined or null to display the default error message

Read more in the [doc](http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the bug. But my big problem is my current code will not trigger the remote rule on lastname and email fields. Do I have to repeat the remote rule 3 times?

Comment: @Alex, the remote rule is only checking the data from one field.  You can use it on all three fields, but each field's data is checked separately.  In other words, the `first_name` field's `remote` rule will only check the data in the `first_name` field.  This will certainly fail unless no two users share the same first name.